# Multi-Language using resolveViewName()

Tags: html, apache, spring-mvc, java-7, spring-3

I need to use resolveViewName() function, but the site is multiple languages. How can I do it?

```
getViewResolver()
    .resolveViewName(velocity, Locale.getDefault())
     .render(model, request, response);
```